# Extract substring from string - regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String say:

```
<encoded:2,Message request>
```

Now I want to extract `2` and `Message request` from the line above.

```
private final String pString = "<encoded:[0-9]+,.*>";
    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pString);

    private void parseAndDisplay(String line) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            while(matcher.find()) {
                String s = matcher.group();
                System.out.println("=====>"+s);

            }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't retrieve it. What is wrong with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define groups in your regex:

```
"<encoded:([0-9]+),(.*?)>"
```

or

```
"<encoded:(\\d+),([^>]*)"
```

Comment: In Java to pass \ literal it must be written as \\. So \d should be \\d. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Jatin you need to capture groups. Instead `group()` use `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Comment: +1 for showing two options—lazy quantifier or negated character class.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
    String s = "<encoded:2,Message request>";
    String s1 = s.replaceAll("<encoded:(\\d+?),.*", "$1");
    String s2 = s.replaceAll("<encoded:\\d+?,(.*)>", "$1");
```

Comment: better to use replaceFirst?

Comment: It works too, but I dont think it makes any difference in this situation

Comment: if message request contained a similar innner tag, it would fail right?

Comment: tested "<encoded:2,Message > request>" s2 returns "Message > request"

Comment: +1 for simple code to find one string in another, but I am afraid that `line` in OP example will have more `<encoded..>` tags so this solution will need some improvements.

Comment: Sure, in this case replaceAll won't work, we will need to use Matcher.find

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"<encoded:([0-9]+),([^>]*)"
```

Also, as suggested in other comments, use `group(1)` and `group(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
         Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<encoded:(\\d+)\\,([\\w\\s]+)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("<encoded:2,Message request>");

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```